# Odd prettier indentation with React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using the default setting for Prettier. Prettier changes this

```
export function SideNavComponent({
  classes,
}) {
  return (
    <SideNav
      customUserMenuRootContent={(
        <p className={classes.timestamp}>
          <span className={classes.lastLogin}>{LAST_LOGIN} </span>
          {moment(window.localStorage.lastLogin).format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)}
        </p> 
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

to this

```
export function SideNavComponent({ classes }) {
  return (
    <SideNav
      customUserMenuRootContent={(
        <p className={classes.timestamp}>
          <span className={classes.lastLogin}>{LAST_LOGIN} </span>
          {moment(window.localStorage.lastLogin).format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)}
        </p>
)}
    />
  );
}
```

Prettier config:

```
module.exports = {
    singleQuote: true,
    trailingComma: 'all',
    printWidth: 99
};
```

Any ideas why it's being formatting that way?

Comment: Can you post your prettier config as well?

Comment: it's because of your `printWidth` value; if you want to retain original format, you can either set it to maybe 20 but will surely break another formatting as well; thus, prettier is working as expected.